# codeigniter routing issue

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I had my users profile at

```
www.domain.com/user/username
```

and moved it at

```
www.domain.com/username
```

but this required to add most `classes functions` into the `routes.php` file in the config and if i want to add new features to my app i will need to add all the functions into the `routes.php` file which doesnt sound good practice...

What is the best way that other deal with it on CodeIgniter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems i got the answer

what i did is add the below code for every controller i have

```
$route['controller'] = "controller";
$route['controller/(:any)'] = "controller/$1";
```

and this code at the bottom

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can do it the other way round - make a whitelist of usernames that can't be taken (those would be names of your controllers, like `admin`, `contact`, etc...) and route anything except the whitelist items.